# Why can a private member be return?

Tags: java

The following sample code is from website.

`sInstance` is a private member, it means that it's only be access in the class `LittleMonkProviderHolder`.

Why can the function `getInstance()` return `LittleMonkProviderHolder.sInstance` ? Thanks!

**Code**

```
public class FloatActionController {

    private FloatActionController() {
    }

    public static FloatActionController getInstance() {
        return LittleMonkProviderHolder.sInstance;  //Return a private member!!!
    }


    private static class LittleMonkProviderHolder {
        private static final FloatActionController sInstance = new FloatActionController();
    }

}
```

Comment: the concept of access scopes is rather self-explanatory, when looking what the keywords exactly mean.

Comment: @MartinZeitler You might want to read the question again. It's a valid question, why can a private member be accessed by it's outer class.

Comment: @Kartik keyword `private` has access level `class`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html - this can be an advance and dis-advance of inner classes, depending what one intends to accomplish.

Comment: Ah, I missed the key aspect of this question upon initial skimming. Indeed, the question is asking _"why is a (static) inner class private instance visible to the outer class."_ I was expecting the basic "type vs instance" question & crafted a useless explanatory answer before reading more closely.

Comment: looks like you are missing java basics. Take some time to go through some basic java tutorial to eliminate similar future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a Bill Pugh singleton to me.  There is nothing wrong with *returning* a private member from a private inner class in the `FloatActionController` class. The `private` specifier only means that trying to *access* the field directly via:

```
FloatActionController.LittleMonkProviderHolder.sInstance
```

would fail, as both the inner class and its member are private.